# android swipe left right content?

Tags: android

i have `jSON` array content image `url` and caption  , the list content over 100 `object`

this is example code :

```
[{"url":"http:\/\/web.com\/image\/1.jpg","cap":"image 1"},{"url":"http:\/\/web.com\/image\/2.jpg","cap":"image 2"},{"url":"http:\/\/web.com\/image\/3.jpg","cap":"image 3"}]
```

what i am looking for is this :

[image]

sure its must content left right pagination swipe picture and caption

is there any asapter can do that ? can any one lead me what i have to use `pager` or `fragment` or any thing else ?

please guys any advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this [AndroidViewPagerGallery](https://github.com/manishkpr/AndroidViewPagerGallery)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
}
```

and this adapter you can customize it to create layout and change the picture and captions

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    private int[] GalImages = new int[] {
        R.drawable.one,
        R.drawable.two,
        R.drawable.three
    };
    ImageAdapter(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return GalImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
      return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
      int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
      imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
      imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
      ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
      return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
      ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
  }
```